# How to set first responder for NSTextView?

Tags: macos, nstextview, becomefirstresponder

I am using multiple NSTextViews inside a NSTableView. Each textView is added on the cell of table view. But problem occurs when i try to select the textView. Sometimes, cursor comes on textView easily but most of the times, the cursor don't come to textView on single click. Delegate associated with the textView is fired at once when textView is clicked:

```
- (void)textViewDidChangeSelection:(NSNotification *)aNotification {

}
```

How can i set the control of cursor to the selected textView on single click..???

Please guide me i am new to mac development...

Comment: You should post the code also

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved the problem... Actually another view was shielding the textView due to which textView was not selectable. I just moved textView to NSWindowAbove and it started working...